# How to do loops with timestamps in a PostgreSQL function?

Tags: c#, postgresql

I'm new to PostgreSQL and have a difficult problem that I need to code into a PostgreSQL function.

Here is the situation.

In one table, dx, records are entered with a posting time, tposted, and a Boolean for chronicity.

```
  table dx
      tposted  timestamp
      chronic  Boolean
```

Now there will be several thousand records. Upon calling somefunction(), I need the return to show every record chronologically by tposted PLUS return every record with chronic = true WITH every date more recent then the tposted of the chronic record.

As an example:

```
     table dx
     record    tposted   chronic
      1        01/01/01    False
      2        02/02/02    False
      3        03/03/03    True       <--needs to be carried forward
      4        04/04/04    False
      5        05/05/05    False
      6        06/06/06    True       <--needs to be carried forward
      7        07/07/07    False
      8        08/08/08    False
```

The output needs to be a repetition of all records where chronic = true:

```
    Output Table
          tposted   dx.record
          01/01/01    1
          02/02/02    2
          03/03/03    3
          04/04/04    3     <-- carried forward
          04/04/04    4
          05/05/05    3     <--- carried forward
          05/05/05    5
          06/06/06    3     <--- carried forward
          06/06/06    6
          07/07/07    3     <--- carried forward
          07/07/07    6     <--- carried forward
          07/07/07    7
          08/08/08    3     <--- carried forward
          08/08/08    6     <--- carried forward
          08/08/08    8
```

My feeling is that I need to process each date, one at a time. With each date go back to all records before that date marked with chronic = true, return those records and then proceed to the next date.

Can this be done? (or is there a better way??)  Thanks for all help on this.

(I'm including a tag for C# as I am not opposed to accomplishing this with Link if necessary).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I am assumming that `tposted dates are unique within the table.
Under this assumption the following query should work:

```
select t2.tposted, t1.record, 
       '<-- carried forward' as comment
from dx t1
join dx t2
on t1.chronic='True' and t1.tposted < t2.tposted
union all
select tposted, record, null
from dx
order by tposted, comment, record
```

Demo: http://sqlfiddle.com/#!15/e6456/17

If this assumption is not true, you need to change a join condition.
For example, assumming that `record` values are unique and they are incremented chronogically, then you can try `t1.record < t2.record` in the join instead of `t1.tposted < t2.tposted`.

Comment: Unfortunately, 'tposted' dates are not unique in the dx table. In fact, records are 'unique' by their record id (serial) and/or the combination of 'tposted' and a 'cdesc' description field. Thanks.

Comment: Much thanks for the link to sqlfiddle! It helped a lot.